# AppFog - Error (JSON 503): <?xml version="1.0" encoding="u

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, appfog

I'm trying to deploy a Rails app (2.3.8) on AppFog using the commands:

```
af login
af update app_name
```

I'm using update because the app is already existing on AppFog. However, I keep getting this error:

```
Error (JSON 503): <?xml version="1.0" encoding="u...
```

It happens after uploading the files. Running `af update` usually gives me that error. In fact, I've only ran that command successfully once in around a hundred times. I've tried deploying on different times around the clock, but no success. I've also tried using different servers of AppFog (US, EU, SG) but no luck either.

Anyone else having the same issue? Does anyone know a workaround for this? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same error too, and it seems that's got to do something with the size of the app.
Here's the post in the google group I posted and the responses I got.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/appfog-users/kIMXXYQTl2A

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Cool, this did the trick. Though I had to shrink the app size to under 2mb, and had to delete and create the app again using `af push`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I meet the same error as you,here is solution of this erro
[a link](http://ruby-china.org/wiki/appfog-deploy)
You need do this:

> > af push --runtime ruby193

or do this:

> > af update yourappname --runtime ruby193

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps, each time an error message appears :

```
$ rvm use 1.9.3
$ gem install af 
$ af login
```

your username & password

then `af update your_application`

It works

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, but I just need to retry to upload code. It happens because appfog server had some issue that make your service unavailable. Please login console and check your service, then run `af update` again.